# Vue call method asynchronous multiple times

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, vue.js

I have a component which loads items using a load method.

I need to have another method that calls the load method multiple times to load a much larger chunk of data.

I need to make asynchronous requests, wait for the first time is done before running it again.

I guess I need to set up a promise or something, but I failed to do so. Anyone have a good solution for this?

Here is a jsfiddle Explaining my issue.
https://jsfiddle.net/qa5sm7hj/21/

Here is the javascript component itself

```
new Vue({
  el: '#cmp',
  data: {
    items: []
  },
  methods: {
        loadItems() {
        //pretend this is an http request that fetches data and then push them to items array.
        ['one', 'two', 'three'].forEach(item => {
            this.items.push(item);
      });
    },
    ultraLoadItems() {
      for (var i = 1; i <= 5;i++) {
        //I want to load new items 5 time in a row
        //and wait until each iteration is done.
        this.loadItems();
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Here is HTML

```
<div id="cmp">
  <div>
    <button @click="ultraLoadItems">Ultra load</button><br>
    <span>{{ items.length }}</span>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="item in items">{{ item }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to do some research into promises, and their associated callbacks.  What you are describing is making a request, and then attaching a callback to that request promise that will do another request once it is done.

Answer (score 0):

This is my Solution

```
new Vue({
  el: '#cmp',
  data: {
    items: []
  },
  methods: {
        loadItems() {
        let vm = this;
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        ['one', 'two', 'three'].forEach(item => {
          vm.items.push(item);
        });
        resolve();
      })            
    },
    ultraLoadItems() {
        for (var i = 1; i <= 5;i++) {
        this.loadItems();
      }
    }
  }
})
```